# При клике изменить фон блоков div

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица из `div` тегов.

Как изменить фон только одной строки при клике на строку?

```css
.rels-right-block{display:block;} 
 .valfirst{height:20px; width:20px; text-align:center;  float:left;}
 .valexp_numb{height:20px; width:150px; text-align:center; padding:1px 0; float:left;}
  .valexp_numb .exp1{height:20px; width:50px; float:left;}
  .valexp_numb .exp2{height:20px; width:50px; float:right;} 
 .exp_numb{height:29px; padding:3px 0; float:left;}
 .point_dest{height:29px; padding:3px 0; float:left;}
 .valpoint_dest{height:20px; width:200px; text-align:left; text-transform:uppercase;  border:1px solid #666666; padding:2px 0 0 6px;}
```

```html
<div class="rels-right-block">
<div class="vals">

 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>1</div>-<div class='exp2'>2</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">3er</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>66</div>-<div class='exp2'>34</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">ert</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>113</div>-<div class='exp2'>gg</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">12</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>hik</div>-<div class='exp2'>www</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">123</div>
 </div>
 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: при клике на что?

Comment: @MasterAlex при клике на строку

Comment: У кого нибудь есть варианты

Comment: @Xfirab, сейчас напишу

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ghmy23w8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.listRel').click(function() {
    $('.listRel').removeClass('color');
    $(this).addClass('color');
  });
});
```

```css
.rels-right-block{display:block;} 
.valfirst{height:20px; width:20px; text-align:center;  float:left;}
.valexp_numb{height:20px; width:150px; text-align:center; padding:1px 0; float:left;}
.valexp_numb .exp1{height:20px; width:50px; float:left;}
.valexp_numb .exp2{height:20px; width:50px; float:right;} 
.exp_numb{height:29px; padding:3px 0; float:left;}
.point_dest{height:29px; padding:3px 0; float:left;}
.valpoint_dest{height:20px; width:200px; text-align:left; text-transform:uppercase;  border:1px solid #666666; padding:2px 0 0 6px;}
.color {background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rels-right-block">
<div class="vals">

 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>1</div>-<div class='exp2'>2</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">3er</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>66</div>-<div class='exp2'>34</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">ert</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>113</div>-<div class='exp2'>gg</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">12</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="listRel">
  <div class="valfirst">-</div>
  <div class="valexp_numb"><div class='exp1'>hik</div>-<div class='exp2'>www</div></div>
  <div class="valpoint_dest">123</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на javascript

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghmy23w8/2/)

```js
var classSelector,
  classElements,
  startActive;

classSelector = '.listRel';

classElements = document.querySelectorAll(classSelector);

startActive = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
    classElements[i].classList.remove('listRel-current');
  }
  this.classList.add('listRel-current');
};

for (var i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
  classElements[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startActive);
}
```

```css
.rels-right-block {
  display: block;
}
.valfirst {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.valexp_numb {
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 0;
  float: left;
}
.valexp_numb .exp1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.valexp_numb .exp2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
}
.exp_numb {
  height: 29px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  float: left;
}
.point_dest {
  height: 29px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  float: left;
}
.valpoint_dest {
  height: 20px;
  width: 210px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  padding: 2px 0 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.listRel {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 210px;
}
.listRel-current {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="rels-right-block">
  <div class="vals">

    <div class="listRel">
      <div class="valfirst">-</div>
      <div class="valexp_numb">
        <div class='exp1'>1</div>-
        <div class='exp2'>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="valpoint_dest">3er</div>
    </div>

    <div class="listRel">
      <div class="valfirst">-</div>
      <div class="valexp_numb">
        <div class='exp1'>66</div>-
        <div class='exp2'>34</div>
      </div>
      <div class="valpoint_dest">ert</div>
    </div>

    <div class="listRel">
      <div class="valfirst">-</div>
      <div class="valexp_numb">
        <div class='exp1'>113</div>-
        <div class='exp2'>gg</div>
      </div>
      <div class="valpoint_dest">12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="listRel">
      <div class="valfirst">-</div>
      <div class="valexp_numb">
        <div class='exp1'>hik</div>-
        <div class='exp2'>www</div>
      </div>
      <div class="valpoint_dest">123</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте и моё решение:

```js
(function() {
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

  for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      for(var j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++) {
        blocks[j].classList.remove("active");
      }

      this.classList.add("active");
    }, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
.block {
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.block:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}

.block div {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block.active {
  background-color: orange;
}

.block div:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="name">
      John
    </div>
    <div class="surname">
      Sleiden
    </div>
    <div class="born">
      1985.12.12
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="block">
    <div class="name">
      Ben
    </div>
    <div class="surname">
      Stuart
    </div>
    <div class="born">
      1976.12.12
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую